# @angular/compiler-cli@4.2.5 requires typescript@'>=2.1.0 <2.4.0' but 2.4.1 was found instead

Tags: angular, visual-studio, typescript

I created a new Angular project using Visual Studio 2017, asp.net core, 
using this sample  https://dzone.com/articles/crud-operations-with-aspnet-core-using-angular-5-a

tried to publish using  Visual Studio 2017, with the option Publish, but I read that I should use > ng build --prod, after that I got the error,  I'm stuck there, the project works when I run from Visual Studio locally, but I want to move to IIS in a Azure Windows 2016 server.  any help?  Thanks

[Error when tried to build application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FQaC.jpg)

Comment: You could run the `npm` command suggested in the error message to install a version of Typescript compatible with your Angular project.

Comment: Thanks, that was the first thing I did,  no luck,  the problem still,  I tried few solutions, but I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Typescript version 2.2.0
use the below command

```
npm install typescript@2.2.0 --save
```

Comment: use can install any version between 2.1.0 and 2.4.0...it should work